# Is it safe to use Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR)? How can value type get changed in DLR?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dynamic-language-runtime

As I recently found the DLR, I see it's possible to change value types in runtime easily. Is there going to be any memory problems or exceptions during runtime? How does the DLR get to change the value without any exceptions and/or memory errors? Is address of object the same after changing the value? what happens to the old value/object and address/reference of it?

```
dynamic dyn = "String";

Console.Write(dyn);

dyn = 123;

Console.Write(dyn * 2);

dyn = new Action<string>(Test);

dyn("ABC");

static void Test(string t)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as safe as you make it.

Under the hood, a variable of type `dynamic` actually has type `object`. So there is nothing special going on when you assign `"String"`, `123`, or `new Action<string>(…)` to it. You perhaps already know that you could easily do the same with any `object` variable. The only magic that is going on is boxing for value-typed values (e.g. `123`), but again, that is not something particular to `dynamic`, but has happened with assignments such as `object x = 123;` since the first version of .NET.

(To be extra-clear: You are not changing any value when you re-assign to your `dyn` variable. You're simply making `dyn` reference a different value.)

The magic that does happen with `dynamic` is late binding. That is, every time you invoke a method, or a property, or an operator, etc. on such a variable, the actual method, property, operator etc. is not yet known at compile-time; it is chosen at runtime. For each such call, the compiler generates code that will inspect the variable's current value's type and tries to select a suitable method, property, operator, etc. to be called. If such a one is found, it is invoked; otherwise you get an exception.

Let's look at a different example:

```
dynamic a = 123;
Console.WriteLine(a * 2); // OK

dynamic b = "123";
Console.WriteLine(b * 2); // will throw an exception
```

The exception thrown by the second block is interesting here:

> *`RuntimeBinderException`: Operator `*` cannot be applied to operands of type `string` and `int`.*

You did not get some arithmetic exception because it was never even attempted to multiply `"123"` by `2`. The runtime could not even find a suitable `*` operator to call in the first place! The runtime inspected the types of `b` (`string`) and `2` (`int`) and tried to find an operator `*` for these two types, but couldn't find any… therefore the exception.

(The same happened for `a * 2` of course; there the runtime saw that `a` has runtime-type `int` (since it references the boxed integer `123` at that specific moment) and so does `2`, and an operator `*` for two `int`s was found & thus invoked.)

Btw., because of the late-binding nature of `dynamic` variables (i.e. suitable actions on them are only figured out at runtime), IntelliSense (a compile-time feature) does not work with them.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `dyn` contains a reference and each time you reassign `dyn` you reassign this reference. Whatever `dyn` referenced before being reassigned can now be garbage collected if no other references exists to that object. When you assign a value type to a `dynamic` the value will be boxed so `dyn = 123` will create a boxed int on the heap and when `dyn` is reassigned this boxed int can be garbage collected.

What `dynamic` does is that any methods called that involves the `dynamic` variabled is decided at run-time based on the run-time type of the object referenced by the variable as opposed to "normal" C# where methods are determined at compile time or is a simple virtual method table lookup. And if you try to do something that is impossible you will get an exception but that is expected when using `dynamic`.

So to sum it up, a `dynamic` variable contains a reference just like any other reference type variable. However, the code generated when a `dynamic` variable is used is very different because the actual method called can only be determined at run-time.